# How to replace all of specific entry in a column with new entry

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a column that is filled with string entries of {A,B,C}, but want to replace all entries of A with B. 
What function would be best to do this? Thanks, I'm still an R newbie!

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output to make it very clear exactly how your data is structured and what you need to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gsub` allows you to pattern match replace values in a vector as in the following small example.

```
df = data.frame(sample(100,12), letters[1:3])
df[,2] = gsub("a","b",df[,2])
```